# how to change the playing speed of AVPlayerItem in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayeritem

I am using a library named Jukebox , to play audios files , I want to make it player faster or slower.
It inherits AVPlayerItem , but I can't find how.
Any one can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate) rate property below

```
var rate: Float { get set }
```

For instance:-

```
if let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: yourUrl), let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem) {
//This will update your player speed faster or slower accordingly
  player.rate = Float(rateValue)
}
```

Comment: avplayeritem has no rate property

Comment: These are get only properties !

Comment: I updated the answer back. Pls let me know if this make sense?